# How to access Vuex map helpers with Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am using Composition API in Vue2. Can you tell me how to access `mapState` with composition API? I want to watch for state changes as well. Hence I would have to use it within setup function as well (not only in return). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Vuex map helpers aren't supported (yet?) in the Vue 2 or Vue 3 composition API, and this [proposal](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1725) for them has been stalled for a while.

You'll have to manually create a computed like in the [docs](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html#accessing-state-and-getters):

```js
const item = computed(() => store.state.item);
```

A more complete example:

```js
import { computed } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    const item = computed(() => store.state.item);

    return {
      item
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the Vuex mapper helpers supported yet in Vuex 4?

Comment: Looks like no after following the proposal. Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

For me the trick was using the vuex-composition-helper npm package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-composition-helpers

```js
import { useState, useActions } from 'vuex-composition-helpers';

export default {
    props: {
        articleId: String
    },
    setup(props) {
        const { fetch } = useActions(['fetch']);
        const { article, comments } = useState(['article', 'comments']);
        fetch(props.articleId); // dispatch the "fetch" action

        return {
            // both are computed compositions for to the store
            article,
            comments
        }
    }
}
```